# SQL query to get all users from 1 table ordered by amount appearing in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

- Users - id, name
- Rooms - uid

I want to get all users ordered by SUM of appearing in Rooms table (for example, where users.id = rooms.uid). Also I want to get how many times each person have been appeard there.

For example:

```
Solomon - 5 
Igor - 3 
Thomas - 1 
John - 0 
Total: 9
```

What would be the right query to do so?

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I would add an in-between table between users and rooms holding (userid)(roomid)(count)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.share,
        COUNT(b.uid) TotalVisits
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN visits b
            ON a.id = b.uid
GROUP   BY a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.share
ORDER   BY TotalVisits DESC
```

This worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated, with *three* important SQL components:  `left join`, `group by`, and `rollup`:

```
select u.uid, count(r.uid) as cnt
from users u left join
     rooms r
     on u.uid = r.uid
group by u.uid with rollup
order by (case when u.uid is not null then cnt desc else -1 end);
```

Comment: #1221 - Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: You can't put `ORDER BY` inside parentheses like that.